# Saída de um método ou evento - C# / WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, eventos, método, devexpress

Eu estou utilizando um `return` para poder sair do evento `textEstado_Validate`. O problema é que quando ele sai desse evento, ele entra no `textEstado_KeyDown`.
Como posso fazer para que ele não entre em mais nenhum método e nenhum evento?

```
private void textEstado_Validate(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
{
    Ação...

    return;
}

private void textEstado_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Ação...
}
```

Existe um comando pra isso?

O textEstado é um TextEdit, componente do DevExpress

Comment: Qual o tipo do `textEstado`?

Comment: Um campo de texto, editei a descrição

Comment: é igual o TextBox;

Comment: Um TextBox "comum" não tem um evento de validação que receba um `ValidationEventArgs`. @Emerson, se a classe `ValidationEventArgs` tem uma propriedade `Handled`, você pode setá-la para `true` que o evento pára de ser propagado.

Comment: Eu tentei dessa forma, mesmo assim ele entrou no outro evento.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a propriedade `Handled` de `ValidationEventArgs`.

Isso fará com que o evento pare de ser propagado.

```
private void textEstado_Validate(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
{
    //Ação...

    e.Handled = true;
    return;
}
```

Veja na documentação de [`ValidationEventArgs`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfEditorsValidationEventArgsMembersTopicAll) do DevExpress

Comment: Já tentei dessa forma @jbueno, ele continua executando e entra no evento textEstado_KeyDown.
Ele entra nesse evento pq eu digito um caracter, correto?

Comment: O `KeyDown` é disparado sempre que alguma tecla é clicada quando o foco está no componente. Pensei que dessa forma funcionaria, vou criar um projeto de teste para verificar.

Comment: Eu agradeço qualquer ajuda...